# Django select query with where clause

Tags: django, django-models

Sheet_Table

```
id  ref_id   name   data 
1     10      A     9078
2     10     AAA    6789
3     12      C     345
```

Sheet Model have multiple Columns id,ref_id,name,data

Now i want to write this query in django 

`select data from Sheet_Table where ref_id=10`

Here Model/Table name is Sheet_Table

Comment: But your filter (on the `id`), will normally only return *one* element I guess?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks Edited that part

Comment: This example code is very confusing.  Where are `sheet` and `data` coming from?  What is `filter_by`?  Under normal operation, `Sheet.objects.filter(id=id)` would give you a queryset with zero or one element in it.  For more general understanding, have you tried looking at [the django query docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/)?

Comment: @RishiGn hi i have changed the problem description please check if you can help me with this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty explicitly stated in the django [doc on queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects) that `filter(foo=bar)` evaluates to a `WHERE` clause.  In your specific case, try this to get a list of just the `data` elements (if your model is actually called `Sheet_Table`?):

```py
Sheet_Table.objects.filter(ref_id=10).values_list('data', flat=True)
```

or you can leave off the `values_list` part if you want to iterate over the model objects (e.g., if you want to examine `id` as well as `data`).